# Optimize Select on a CLOB field ine DB oracle

Tags: oracle, indexing, clob

So, I got a table, which cotnains somes `CLOB` fields. And I found that they were increasing the result time.

I tried to add `INDEX` on this field, but apparently , it cannot be done on `CLOB` field.

But I still want to improve the response on my Select.

How can I optimize it if it's possible?

My table got like 50 fields, 5/6 `CLOB` and 2/3 `BLOB`(the others are number or `Varchar2`.

I don't have Index on this `CLOB` field, because it is impossible.

My query is a simple Select who got all fields of my table(without distinct, without order by clause). Just a `SELECT` ... `FROM` ...
AND 2 `LEFT JOIN` on the same table :

`t_instance` contains an `id_winner` and an `id_loser`.
A person can be an asker(in `t_myTable`), a winner in `t_instance`, or a loser.
I search all lines in myTable, where `id_asker`, `id_winner` or `id_loser` is the connected person (has a unique number to refer, that I use as number in my request)

```
SELECT p.id (and all the 50 fields)
FROM t_myTable p 
LEFT JOIN t_instance iwd on iwd.id_object = p.id 
LEFT JOIN t_instance iwv on iwv.id_object = p.id  
WHERE(id_asker = 'number' OR iwd.id_winner = 'number' OR iwv.id_loser ='number' )
```

I do not have errors, but I just want to know if it's possible to have better response time with my `SELECT`.

Thank you.

Comment: Include some meaningful detail and people may be able to help out: table/index structure, the SQL query you're using and explain plan you're getting.

Comment: Please provide stats of the table, size of data retrieved, also let us know you access the original DB from a different machine (Network Overhead!!). Have you tried any stats gathering?

Comment: @Andrew not the Saint is this what you were talking about?

Comment: @realspirituals it's all varchar2(50) or number except for the CLOB and BLOb fields (as describe in question). Only thos two types are huge. Yes it is on network. What's stats gathering?

Comment: @Zaphod... You question states "My query is a simple Select who got all fields of my table(without distinct, without order by clause). Just a SELECT ... FROM ... AND 2 LEFT JOIN on the same table" But what we see from the query is that it has 2 LEFT JOIN on a different table. So even the where clause might slowdown your output. Just try to select non LOB columns and post the EXPLAIN PLAN.. Also post EXPLAIN PLAN while selecting LOB columns. Stats .. refer here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/stats.htm

Comment: So, according to what you say, this are the LEFT JOIN and not the LOB fields. Indeed, the cost is 12(that is what the explain plain give us? ) with the join(+ where clause), and 2 without...

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e16638/ex_plan.htm - Google is your friend. Also, state where id_asker field is and if you have indexes on id_asker, id_winner and id_loser fields, how many records you have in each table, how many distinct values you have for each of those 3 columns above and what you expect the response times to be.